# Leading Zero is getting truncated in Oracle SQL query while doing currency format

Tags: sql, string, oracle, select

Query:

```
select to_char('0.00', '$999,999,999,999,999.99') from dual;
```

Actual output:

```
$.00
```

Expected Output:

```
$0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
select to_char('0.00', '$999,999,999,999,990.9') from dual;
```

The `0` on the first digit forces Oracle to display something, even if the digit is not significant. I also changed the specifier to have just one decimal number instead of two .

Comment: Also note that "to_char('0.00',<format mask>) is actually sending a character string to to_char.  That because you enclosed your number in single-quotes, making it a string, not a number.  This forced oracle to do an implicit TO_NUM on your number-that-is-really-a-string.  What you want is "select to_char(0.00,<format mask>) -- without the single quotes around the number.  In your case the end result is the same, but it is sloppy coding and such habits _will_ come back to bite you some day.